# Does F# support partial classes?

Tags: f#

Does F# support partial classes?

I prefer to partition my class into different responsibilities using C#'s partial class feature.

For a ViewModel, I would like to separate the command support in my viewmodel from the properties in my viewmodel.

Is it possible to split my class across multiple files?

Comment: Does this question (and answers) help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4376275/2258